# passing username to form but username returns null c#

Tags: c#, winforms

This code is to return the value of textbox in the Login form.

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public string returnUsername()
    {
        string username = textBox1.Text;
        return username;
    }
}
```

This code is to allow the ChangePass form to show.

```
public partial class Mainmenu_Employee : Form
{
    private void changePasswd_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Login login = new Login();
        ChangePass passwd = new ChangePass(login);
        passwd.Show();
    }
}
```

This code is to take the username from Login form so that I can change the password of the username.

```
    public partial class ChangePass : Form
    {
       Login login = null; //parent form
       Mainmenu_Employee main = new Mainmenu_Employee();


       public ChangePass(Login login1)
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           login = login1;
       }

       private void buttonChangePass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

           Model_DB_Employee emp = new Model_DB_Employee();
           //Login login = new Login();
           string username = login.returnUsername();


           if (textBoxNewPass.Text == string.Empty || textBoxConfirmPass.Text == string.Empty)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Field cannot be empty!");
           }
           else
           {
               if (textBoxNewPass.Text == textBoxConfirmPass.Text)
               {

                   try
                   {

                       emp.changePasswd(username,textBoxConfirmPass.Text);
                       MessageBox.Show(username);
                       MessageBox.Show("Password updated!");
                       this.Hide();
                       main.Show();
                   }
                   catch(SystemException ex)
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("Password not updated" + ex);
                   }

               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match!");
               }
           }
       }
```

Change password function:

```
    public void changePasswd(string username, string newpass) //change password
    {
        Model_Employee emp = new Model_Employee();

        //Hasher hash = new Hasher(); //call hasher class for hashing
        //string hashed;
        //string salt = emp.generateSalt(); //generate random salt
        //newpass = newpass + salt; //append salt to newpass
        //hashed = hash.encryption(newpass); //hash newpass


        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
        {

            if ((string)empTab.Rows[i]["username"] == username)//check if ID matches
            {
                empTab.Rows[i]["passwd"] = newpass;  //set passwd to hash new password                

                //check if dataset has changes
                if (dataset.HasChanges())
                {
                    //update database
                    dbAdapter.Update(dataset, "employee");
                    MessageBox.Show("Employee Updated!");
                    refreshTable();

                }
                else
                {
                    refreshTable();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I am trying to change a user's password when he is logged in.

1. When he logs in, I want to capture his username through a textbox.
2. After he logs in, there will be a main menu displayed.
3. The user needs to click on the change password link and a change password form will appear.

Therefore, I need to pass the username from the login form to the change password form in order to use a change password function. However, the issue I am facing now is that the username does not get passed from the login form to the change password form.

Comment: When does the `username` get set? I see no code in the `Login` form to do that.

Comment: "Is there anything wrong with my code?" Yes, the fact that you're mashing all together business logic and UI, which is what winforms forces you to do. Quickly, switch to WPF before it's too late! =)

Comment: @HighCore Winforms doesn't force you to, it's just that it allows you to and too many people don't make any attempt to separate them.  When you try to separate them it's quite possible, and not all that hard.

Comment: @OP to your edited question, you need to remove the creation of the Login in the code you posted at first, not everywhere in your code.  The problem was that you were doing it too many times, not that it shouldn't be anywhere in your program.

Comment: @HighCore its possible to mash it all up into a horrible mess with WPF too. Although, it helps you to seperate, and the rendering is finer. WPF is a better choice for new projects.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the line:

```
Login login = new Login();
```

This is shadowing the `login` instance field with a new instance of `Login` as a local variable, so rather than accessing the `Login` created earlier that the user has interacted with, you're accessing a blank one.  You can just delete the above line of code.

Comment: @user1779026 "does not work" doesn't really mean anything.  You need to describe what is happening and how it differs from what you expect to be happening.

Comment: @user1779026 It is important that the relevant code be included in the question itself, not on some external site that is linked.

Comment: @user1779026 You still haven't stated when/where the `Login` form is created/shown for the instance that is actually filled out by the user.  Also the first and fourth code snippets shown aren't really relevant.  You just need to figure out (at this point) how to get the correct login form (or just the username result, really) to the change pass form.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with `Login login = new Login()` you´re shadowing your class instance variable `login`. Try:

```
private void buttonChangePass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Model_DB_Employee emp = new Model_DB_Employee();
   string username = login.returnUsername();

   if (textBoxNewPass.Text == string.Empty || textBoxConfirmPass.Text == string.Empty)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Field cannot be empty!");
   }
   else
   {
       if (textBoxNewPass.Text == textBoxConfirmPass.Text)
       {
           try
           {
               emp.changePasswd(username,textBoxConfirmPass.Text);
               MessageBox.Show(username);
               MessageBox.Show("Password updated!");
               this.Hide();
               main.Show();
           }
           catch(SystemException ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Password not updated" + ex);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match!");
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When, between these two lines, does the `username` in the new `login` get set?

```
Login login = new Login();
string username = login.returnUsername();
```

Comment: So how do I call the very 1st login form instead of creating a new instance?

Comment: @user1779026 That depends a lot on code you haven't shown, namely where do you create/show the Login form that is populated.

Answer (score 0):

You never show the Login form, how do you suppose that someone sets the textBox1 with an actual username?

You need something like this

```
       string username = string.Empty;
       Model_DB_Employee emp = new Model_DB_Employee();
       using(Login login = new Login())
       {      
             if(DialogResult.OK == login.ShowDialog())
              username = login.returnUsername();
       } 
       if(username == string.Empty)
       {
            MessageBox.Show("Username required");
            return;
       }
```

Comment: Presumably he is showing the login form, given that he's describing that he's interacting with it and seeing the variables it's populating in code; he just wasn't properly accessing the correct instance of `Login`.

Comment: @Servy, probably right, but why pass a form when only the username is needed, and why (from a maintenance point of view) disperse the code that handles password and login in that way?

Comment: @There are a lot of things that I would change about both the design and implementation if this was a project I was working on, or if this was a code review, but it's not.  He's asking about a specific problem with a very specific solution.  Your change would result in the form being shown twice; it would take a significant re-work to get everything working this way.  If he was posting on codereview, then the answer would be completely different.